# Rollback not working from Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am acquiring lock on row using "select * from table_name where att1 = 'some_value' for update" query using sqldeveloper. And from SP trying to release the lock using rollback on same row in case of exception but rollback is not working from SP. But if i do rollback from sqldeveloper its working fine and releasing the lock.

please guide me if i am doing anything wrong. Here is my stored procedure.

```
DECLARE
  resource_busy    EXCEPTION;
  resource_busy2   EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (resource_busy, -30006);
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (resource_busy2, -00054);
BEGIN
  counter := 0;

  SELECT COUNT (*)
    INTO counter
    FROM TBLACCOUNT
   WHERE TBLACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_ID = RPAD (ACCT_NUM, 20, ' ');

  IF (counter > 0) THEN
    BEGIN
      SELECT TBLACCOUNT.AVAILABLE_BALANCE, TBLACCOUNT.ACTUAL_BALANCE
        INTO Avail_Bal, Curr_Bal
        FROM TBLACCOUNT
       WHERE TBLACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_ID = RPAD (ACCT_NUM, 20, ' ')
       FOR UPDATE WAIT 1;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN resource_busy OR resource_busy2
      THEN
        ROLLBACK;                      --This rollback is not working.
        RETURN -2;
    END;
  END IF;
END;
```

This SP return -2 whenever i acquire lock using select for update but not doing rollback.

Comment: What are you trying to rollback? Another session is holding a lock on that resource, so your session cannot lock it. Your `rollback` cannot remove the lock that a different session is holding...

Comment: I believe the `ROLLBACK` statement IS working; it's doing everything it's supposed to do per the spec.  If you are encountering an ORA-00054 exception, then your session did not obtain a row lock, because of a conflicting lock from another session.

Answer (score 4):

If you are executing the stored procedure in a different session than the SQL Developer session where you acquired the lock, issuing a rollback will not release the lock.  The SQL Developer session (Session A) holds the lock so nothing the session where the stored procedure is being executed (Session B) does can affect that.  Only Session A can issue the rollback and release the lock.

If you are executing the stored procedure in the same session as the SQL Developer session where you acquired the lock, the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` statement in the stored procedure will not generate an exception because the current session already holds the lock.   That would mean that the stored procedure never enters the `EXCEPTION` block and never issues the `ROLLBACK`.